# Does Cyprus require interview for tourist visa?

Tags: cyprus

I want to visit to Cyprus (Greece) as a tourist. Therefore, I should go to Cyprus Embassy in Moscow. Now, I would like to know that there is an interview or not for visiting Cyprus as a tourist.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "Cyprus (Greece)". Cyprus and Greece are two different countries. Please amend your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'd imagine that our OP means Greek-speaking Cyprus, as opposed to the TRNC (Northern Cyprus)

Comment: Maybe or maybe he thinks Greece and Cyprus are the same country. The so called "TRNC" btw is just land occupied by the Turkey.

Answer (score 1):

There is no interview requirement for Russian citizens living in Russia intending to travel directly from Russia to Cyprus for holiday.

The application process can be done online through the following link:
http://www.mfa.gov.cy/mfa/consulate/consulate_spb.nsf/cgsp12_en/cgsp12_en?OpenDocument